# How do I disable the uppercase/lowercase functionality of the Caps Lock key?

Tags: keyboard

I like to use Caps Lock for Push-to-talk in VOIP software, but it annoys me having to rehit the key to have proper case to type every now and then. Does anyone know an easy way to disable the uppercase/lowercase changing portion of the button, but so it would still work in programs like Mumble/Teamspeak/Ventrilo?

Comment: I just found out that Caps Lock is really frowned upon by a lot of people... I use it all the time for typing an Uppercase character instead of shift (capsLock ON -> letter -> capsLock OFF) and I'm so used to it that I have a minimum of 110 wpm regardless.

Comment: Bwarner: I guess you are right. I just posted in Gaming since I expected more gamers to be familiar with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replying here myself as well, since I found even easier solution. This article has a download file (`.reg` files in a `.zip`) for few easy swaps:

- Caps Lock -> Scroll Lock
- Caps Lock -> CTRL
- Caps Lock -> Shift
- Disable Caps Lock
- Revert changes

Article: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/

Zip: http://www.howtogeek.com/geekers/KeyboardMappings.zip

Answer (score 5):

One thing you could do is follow the steps described [here](http://www.usnetizen.com/fix_capslock.php)

This will allow you to remap your Caps Lock key into something else (I wouldn't recommend Shift/Control as they are very commmon in gaming) like Scroll Lock. Then on your application you set your PushToTalk key to Scroll Lock and voila.

Comment: That worked. Ty.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think its possible to disable caps lock without losing the ability for push to talk since it'll register differently.

However, you can remap it to a more benign key (I usually use scroll lock for push to talk with the thumb button on my mouse).

There are instructions [here that shows you how to map it to shift](http://www.annoyances.org/exec/forum/winxp/r1017256194) on windows xp.  You'll have to dig a little to see how to do it for windows 7 and map it to scroll lock, but the idea is the same.